# Remapping 'eject' with '0/)' on MBP

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook, remapping, eject

My zero key on MBP (the one next to 9), is completely dead. No opening, cleaning, or anything else helps revive it. Anytime I need to press zero, I have to press Fn+M (the keypad zero). Even worse, every time I have to press ')' I have to find it somewhere and paste it.

Can somebody give me a complete solution to remapping 'eject' key (which I never use) to zero/) key? I need it to do 2 things:

- type zero on press
- type ) on shift+press

I'm on Snow Leopard, comfortable with terminal, running on zsh.

P.S. I looked through lots of remapping questions but none help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele)?

Comment: I managed to map my Alt+9 to 0 and Alt+Shift+9 to ) using this tool, so it's almost perfect. However, it doesn't allow to remap eject key, especially to act as normal symbol key. I'll keep this open in case something crazy like this comes up, otherwise you get the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

contrary to your comment [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) can be used to solve at least part of your problem : use eject to type zero *or* ) on press. Just follow the instructions for NoEjectDelay & how to define your own rules (it's xml...). Don't know but by designing your own rules you might be able to even get shift + Eject to work... Just remember there is no autorepeat on the Eject key.

Answer (score 0):

[keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) looks like it will do what you want. I haven't used it but those [reviewing it](http://www.macupdate.com/reviews.php?id=25141) at MacUpdate.com seem to like it.

Comment: I just uninstalled it before asking. It allows mapping to certain hard-coded configurations, not to anything arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom settings in KeyRemap4MacBook by creating a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>ejectto0</name>
    <identifier>ejectto0</identifier>
    <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT, KeyCode::KEY_0</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

For example shift+eject is also changed to shift+0. `ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT | ModifierFlag::NONE` would only apply to eject without modifier keys.

Eject keys have a delay by default, but you can remove it with [NoEjectDelay](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/noejectdelay.html.en). It doesn't enable key repeat though, so this method isn't as useful for mapping eject to forward delete.

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).